# The error of approximation $\ln(2)$ is not larger than $\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

> Show that the error of the approximation $\ln(2)$ is not larger than $\frac{1}{3}$.

---

Taylor formula:

$$\ln⁡(1+x)  ≈x-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k}}x^{k}$$

$$\ln(2) = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k}}$$

I have read the many questions here already ready, but most are solved with integral and we have not yet the topic "integral".

Comment: Perhaps by using the Alternating Series Remainder: $|\ln(2)-(1-1/2)|\leq 1/3$, admitting that $\ln(2)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$

Comment: You did not point out which aprroximated value has that error. For example if one write $\ln2\approx 2$, the error is larger than $\frac13$.